# Relationship between tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have seen ER diagrams and conceptual schema of many databases, but I am still not very clear how do you create table out of it and query them?

For example, below is a schema database and how do create tables out of it and query it?

[image]

Say I need perform a query to find all films that include the keyword “America” within the genre “Action” (genre ID = 126). any ideas?

Comment: That is not an ER diagram. It looks more like a screenshot from Microsoft Access, which has nothing to do with any recognised ER diagram notation or ER modelling conventions.

Comment: Agree with dportas. And since it is Access, the tables are there when you draw them. In other tools, you have a "generate to database" step at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most tools that can create an ER diagram can also generate the SQL statements necessary to implement the database. Otherwise, you have to do it manually, by reading the diagram and translating it yourself into SQL.

So, looking at the ER diagram, you might write

```
CREATE TABLE Film (
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Title VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  Description VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  Year INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (Year > 1900),
  Rating INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 3 CHECK (Rating BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
);
```

This image doesn't show data types (like VARCHAR(35)) and constraints (like Year > 1900), so I just guessed.

Now you just have to insert data into the tables, and you're good to go.

Comment: but how do You create tables by reading this diagram?? is it by using CREATE TABLE command?? I am talking about MySQL not SQL. the above one is sql but I am not familiar with sql.

Comment: @homlyn: But it dportas and Stephanie Page are right--and I'm sure they are--you're looking at an Access database, and the tables are already there. Just insert data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Film.*
  from Film
 inner join FilmGenre on FilmGenre.FilmId = Film.Id
 inner join Genre on Genre.Id = FilmGenre.GenreId
 where Film.Title like '%America%'
   and Genre.Name = 'Action'
```

Comment: If you tell me that you want a Genre "Action", then I don't need to query by genre id 126. But if you want to do it, just replace the last line by "and Genre.Id = 126"